# df.Pivot with duplicate index values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
    ts  VariableName    Location    Value   Notes
0   1   Population      01          99      NaN
1   1   Population      02          117     NaN
2   1   Mean_Age        03          28      NaN
3   1   Percent_Male    01          19      NaN
4   1   Population      03          137     NaN
```

I'd like to make the DF look like this:

```
ts Location Population Mean_Age Percent_Male Notes
1  01       99         45       51           NaN
1  02       117        39       72           NaN
1  03       137        28       43           NaN
...
```

I've tried a few different pivot operations, such as

```
df.reset_index().pivot(index='ts', columns='VariableName', values=['Value', 'Location', 'Notes])
```

but keep running into duplicate index values errors.

There are obviously duplicate values in most of the columns, but the combination of ts+VariableName+Location will be unique. I've looked into some stack/unstack options, but can't get anything to work.

Comment: why mean age=[45,39,28]?

Comment: `df.pivot_table(index=['ts','Location'], columns='VariableName', values='Value')`?

Comment: @QuangHoang that returns `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`

Comment: `df.pivot_table(index=['ts','Location'], columns='VariableName', values='Value', aggfunc='first')`?